# How to concat the formula in all reference cell into one formula by VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

after googled a while seems no one has such question. Basically, I have fews cells has formula and referencing each other. Below is an example. How can I make them into one formula?

```
   A    B       C
1  1  =(A1+C1)  =B2
2       3
```

So, I want to parse them into `=1+3`. How can I do that

Comment: Is it possible for you to use in B: `=(A1+B2)`? I feel like there are more important information we need to help you, because now the setup looks quite strange...

Comment: Why you would do that? I mean, instead of pasting `=1+3`, why not just paste `4`? The advantage of using cell references is recalculation if values change, so typing `=1+3` does not make sense. I would overwrite that with the real value `4`

Comment: @Wizhi no, actually the "destinated" cell may not be integer. I will pass the formula in string and further process it in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily is the answer. I've done similar before.

Casting my mind back, I read in the formula into VBA, i.e.

```
F1 = cells(1,2).Formula
```

Then parse that by operators. i.e.

```
F1b = split(F1, "*", -1)
```

You'll need to do it for all operators and store the operators and their location too though! So I'd advise a custom function that can work with many operators at once rather than using split over every potential operator (even if the custom function uses split).

After getting the various cell addresses, you recurse through them doing the same thing, until you build up two array of arrays, the first containing the tree of cell addresses, the second the tree of operators.

Then you'll need to flatten the tree.

This answer isn't very helpful in terms of code - I started doing a bit and remembered its a can of worms. For instance, do you expect any IF() or AND() within formulae?

Comment: yes, not a easy task. Lucky no IF() AND()in the formula.